# Function to find the most common letter that words ends with in a sentence

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the letter that the most words in a sentence ends with and all the words that end with that letter.

It is my homework and I have tried the split function but it doesn't help and the slice function but it takes too long.

```
var sentence = 'Down by the river there is a man that quiver and shiver, but he needs to deliver a packet that he think is a big racket and a packet of of gum.'

function mostWordsEndsWith (){
    for (var i = 0; i < wordsEndsWith.length; i++) {
        var currentWord = wordsEndWith[i].split('t')
        console.log(currentWord);
    }
 }
 mostWordsEndsWith(sentence);
```

Comment: Why does `split` not help?

Comment: I'm gonna guess you can just loop through an array of words, do ``yourArray[Index].substring(yourArray[index].length - 1, yourArray[index].length);`` and add to a counter as you go. Longwinded, but simple. An even better way of doing it would be to collect the substrings in a seperate array, and then create another loop to loop through those seperate arrays to find the longest one.

Comment: I'd suggest you try until you can at least come up with some code that actually does something - currently your function `mostWordsEndsWith` doesn't even accept the parameter you are trying to call it with and your array `wordsEndsWith` isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: @JoshCrowe your comment should be a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let sentence = 'Down by the river there is a man that quiver and shiver, but he needs to deliver a packet that he think is a big racket and a packet of of gum.';

let words = sentence.match(/(\w+)/g);

let letters = {};

//Create an array of object containing the word and his last latter
words = words.map(function(word) {
  return {
    word: word,
    lastLetter: word.slice(-1)
  }
});

//Add the number of occurence for each letters inside the letters object
words.forEach(function(elem) {
  letters[elem.lastLetter] = letters[elem.lastLetter] || 0;
  letters[elem.lastLetter] ++;
});

//Sort the letters object and take the first one
let mostPresentLetter = Object.keys(letters).sort(function(a, b) {
  return letters[b] - letters[a]
})[0];

//Display the most present letter
console.log("Most present letter : " + mostPresentLetter);
//Display all the letters. map is used to display the word only
console.log("Words : " + words.filter(function(item) {
  return item.lastLetter === mostPresentLetter;
}).map(function(o) {
  return o.word;
}));
```

Comment: @Downvoter some explanation please ? Why does it need a downvote ?

Comment: reviewing your code it seems that `word.slice(-1)` would pick up some punctuation like commas, etc, since the `split` by the space does not guarantee ending with an actual letter, so it is not a good algorithm for word detection

Comment: Same uncommented downvote happened to me, but who cares. I just write answers if the question for some reason has an interesting aspect for me. If there is a productive comment, a hint on what i could improve, then even better - i learned something new. Otherwise, it's just irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

here you have a pretty straightforward method, which is compatible with old JS

```js
var sentence = 'Down by the river there is a man that quiver and shiver, but he needs to deliver a packet that he think is a big racket and a packet of of gum.'

var census = {};
var most;

sentence.match(/(\w+)\b/g).forEach(function(word) {
  var last = word.substr(-1);
  most = most || last;
  census[last] = census[last] || [];
  // a word that appears more than once is counted each time
  census[last].push(word);
  if (census[last].length > census[most].length) {
    most = last;
  }
});

//console.log(census);
console.log('most repeated letter was: ' + most + ' (' + census[most].length + ' times)');
console.log('and corresponding words were: ' + census[most]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way of doing that. Note that it uses several ES6 features, in case compatibility is an issue.

```js
var sentence = "Down by the river there is a man that quiver"
             + " and shiver, but he needs to deliver a packet"
             + " that he think is a big racket and a packet"
             + " of of gum."

function mostWordsEndsWith (str){
  //index for: letter --> { count, words }
  //this is quite a good object itself, however not yet the
  //desired final result
  let endLetterCount = 
         //get array of words
         str.match(/\b\w+\b/g)
            //add information about last letter.
            //There is no error handling, but looking what was
            //matched before, something must go very wrong
            //for it to not match.
            .map((w) => ({
              word: w,
              last: w.match(/(\w)(?:[^\w]|$)/)[1]
            }))
            //create index
            .reduce((p, c) => {
              if (p.hasOwnProperty(c.last)) {
                p[c.last].count++;
                p[c.last].words.push(c.word);
              } else p[c.last] = { count: 1, words: [c.word] };
              return p;
            },
            //ugly, hi javascript...
            //There are lengthy discussions on why objects
            //dont per default work similar to this, not too
            //relevant for this question.
            {
              [Symbol.iterator]: function*(){
                //Here we know exactly what the object is,
                //so issues regarding "own property" are
                //non-existant
                for (prop in this)
                  yield { key: prop, value: this[prop] };
              }
            });
  
  //get the letter with the highest count
  let highestCount = [...endLetterCount].reduce(
    (p, c) => c.value.count > p.value.count ? c : p
  );
  
  //return some nice output format, whatever is wanted.
  return `Letter "${highestCount.key}" occurred most, `
       + `${highestCount.value.count} times: `
       + `${highestCount.value.words}.`;
}

console.log(mostWordsEndsWith(sentence));
```